# Commutative of the matrix ring $M_n(R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I saw 'Matrix ring' in Wikipedia and in the Properties section it says,

> The matrix ring $M_n(R)$ is commutative if and only if R is commutative and n=1

However, for a ring R defined as:

$R=\{0,1,2,3\}$ and $(R,+)$ is defined as Klein four group and $(R,*)$ is defined as $a*b=0$ for all $a ,b\in R$

Then R is certainly a ring and so $M_n(R)$ is a ring under the usual matrix addition and multiplication. And, $M_n(R)$ is commutative. So, I don't really understand the if and only if statement above. Am I doing something wrong or misunderstanding?

Comment: Your ring is trivial

Comment: Klein 4 group has all elements order 2... But how $(R,+)$ is Klein? Isn't it rather $\mathbb{Z}_4$?

Comment: And also note that $M_n(R)$ is commutative when $n=1$ besides of $R$ is commutative. So your example does not disprove it because your example is when $n=2$.

Comment: "This article assumes that R is an associative ring with a unit 1 ≠ 0"

Comment: @LevBan $(R,+)$ can be isomorphic to the Klein group if we decide it is. It's just a definition of the group structure. Also the counter-example of the OP is correct: in a ring $R$ where all products are zero, $M_n(R)$ is commutative for all $n$. But the article explicitly assumes that rings have a non-trivial unit, so there is no contradiction.

Comment: @Captain Lama Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quote from Wikipedia:

This article assumes that $R$ is an associative ring with a unit $1 \ne 0$, although matrix rings can be formed over rings without unity.

This does not apply to your example.